# How to care for my potted avocado plant

Tags: avocado

I’ve been caring for 2 avocado plants grown from a seed for the past 2 years. They’ve survived transplanting and my flatmates not caring for them when I went on holiday. The biggest one has a lot of new growth this month and the smaller one is producing new leaves too.

This past week Britain had a nice bit of sun so I placed them outside as they were in the summer. After a week I have now checked on them and the smaller one has very bronzed leaves. I don’t think this is to do with the water as that’s just the tips, correct? Was the shock of window sun to full sun too much for the little guy?

It’s going to be cloudy and rainy this whole week so I figured I could leave them outside still. What do you advise? I wanna make sure they’re properly cared for! :) [image: The bronze leaves][image: The whole gang][image: another bronze angle]

Answer (score 1):

Your plants are suffering from heat stress, hence the discolouration of the leaves. Take them out of the sun immediately. This is usually the case when people buy older plants from nurseries that have been grown undercover in shade and place them straight away outside in direct light, exposing it to the natural flare of the sun, something that the plant isn't habitual of so the end result is a plant struggling to retain moisture, causing sunburn and leaf scorch. Now this doesn't mean that your plant is gonna die on you. Unless ofcourse if you plan to. Trim off the burnt leaves or simply cut at the edges to only rid the plant of the actual burnt areas around the leaves (those that aren't severely effected). Do however shape it like how an actual leaf would look. To prevent sunburn, plants need to be exposed to direct sunlight gradually, over a period of several days. Also, do not mistake the plant for in need of water as per it's dried out appearance. You'll only end up having to deal with another problem. One that involves an over-watered plant.